# catkin_add_gtest linking error

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Around [this line](https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros/pull/26/files#diff-af3b638bc2a3e6c650974192a53c7291R51) in `CMakeLists.txt`,

```
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(test_mongo_roscpp test/test_mongo_ros.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(test_mongo_roscpp warehouse_ros)
  add_rostest(test/mongo_ros.test)
endif()
```

Running test results in to `undefined reference` error as follows.

```
$ catkin_make run_tests
:
#### Running command: "make run_tests -j8 -l8" in "/home/roslinguini/cws_planning/build"
####
[ 33%] Built target gtest
[ 66%] Built target gtest_main
Linking CXX executable /home/roslinguini/cws_planning/devel/lib/warehouse_ros/test_mongo_roscpp
CMakeFiles/test_mongo_roscpp.dir/test/test_mongo_ros.cpp.o: In function `MongoRos_MongoRos_Test::TestBody()':
test_mongo_ros.cpp:(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to `mongo_ros::dropDatabase(std::string const&, std::string const&, unsigned int, float)'
test_mongo_ros.cpp:(.text+0xf42): undefined reference to `mongo::LT'
test_mongo_ros.cpp:(.text+0xf60): undefined reference to `mongo::GT'
test_mongo_ros.cpp:(.text+0x1839): undefined reference to `mongo::LT'
test_mongo_ros.cpp:(.text+0x22f7): undefined reference to `ros::console::g_initialized'
test_mongo_ros.cpp:(.text+0x2307): undefined reference to `ros::console::initialize()'
:
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [/home/roslinguini/cws_planning/devel/lib/warehouse_ros/test_mongo_roscpp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [warehouse_ros/CMakeFiles/test_mongo_roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [run_tests] Error 2
Invoking "make run_tests -j8 -l8" failed
```

Removing `target_link_libraries` (like following) doesn't seem to change the result. So I assume the error occurs at `catkin_add_gtest` (I have no idea whether linking should occur here though).

```
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(test_mongo_roscpp test/test_mongo_ros.cpp)
endif()
```

How can I fix this?

I've been also trying with `catkin_tools` (the most recently with version 0.4.1) on Travis CI but looks like the result is similar/the same. You can take a look at [a result where the error starts around here](https://travis-ci.org/ros-planning/warehouse_ros/jobs/124528016#L2859).
And full code is [in this PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros/pull/26).

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232397/catkin_add_gtest-linking-error/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your target `test_mongo_roscpp` is only linking against `warehouse_ros` but nothing else. At least `roscpp` is missing as well as something providing the symbols related to mongo.

If you have `find_package()`-ed all dependencies it might be suffcient to link against `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`.

I commented on another CMake problem in your PR: https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros/pull/26/files#r60482049

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-04-20**:
Your comment in [PR](https://goo.gl/rNoxhY) helps me to move forward, thanks!

> Your target test_mongo_roscpp is only linking against warehouse_ros but nothing else.

I thought with `target_link_libraries` I can trasitively link targets, no? [ref](https://goo.gl/dQKbEU)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-04-20**:
No, not across CMake projects.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to add `<test_depend>rosunit</test_depend>` to your `package.xml`.

See: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/gtest_configuration.html

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2